# WSO2 APIManager (v4.1.0) response code 404 after publishing new APIs (needs restart)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have implemented a publisher 1 new API on WSO2 v4.1.0 system, the API status has been Published, but after I Subscriptions and call the API by Postman, I get 404 error code. In log carbon, it says API not found. .

I have tried several ways like:

- Delete the Application and publish a new API
- Dupplicate adds a new API with the same information as Application before.

The result is still 404 error code.

In case if I restart wso2 apim, the API works normally, no more 404 error code.

Has anyone encountered the same error as me? Please assist me with the solution.

This is my deployment.toml, and I run on only one server (not use loadbalance)

```
[server]
hostname = "***.****.****.****
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "******"
password = "******"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database_unique_id"

#mssql database
[database.apim_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://***.****.****.****:****;databaseName=WSO2AM_INT_DB;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "*******"
password = "******
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://***.****.****.****:****;databaseName=WSO2_SHARED_INT_DB;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "*****"
password = "******"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"

[database.stats_db]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://***.****.****.****:****;databaseName=WSO2_STATS_INT_DB;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "*******"
password = "*******"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
type = "hybrid"
provider = "wso2"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://***.****.****.****:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://***.****.****.****:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://***.****.****.****:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://localhost:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
auth_token = ""

[apim.devportal]
url = "https://***.****.****.****:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

#mssql database
[database.local]
type = "mssql"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://***.****.****.****:****;databaseName=WSO2_CARBON_INT_DB;SendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true"
username = "******"
password = "*****"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://***.****.****.****:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[oauth.grant_type.token_exchange]
enable = true
allow_refresh_tokens = true
iat_validity_period = "1h"

# Enabling Zipkin Tracing
[apim.open_tracer]
remote_tracer.enable = true
remote_tracer.name = "zipkin"
remote_tracer.properties.hostname = "***.****.****.****"
remote_tracer.properties.port = "9411"
```

Sincerely thank you,

Comment: When you initially create, deploy, and publish the API, do you see that it is deployed to the gateway successfully in carbon logs?

Comment: Did you try the Try Out option in the DevPortal or curl command, and is the same response?

Comment: I tried the command and now the API is published:
curl -k -H "Authorization: Basic *********=" "https://*:9443/api/am/publisher/v3/apis"

Response:
{
      "id": "*******",
      "name": "***ABC",
      "context": "/internal/ekyc",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "provider": "admin",
      "type": "HTTP",
      "lifeCycleStatus": "PUBLISHED",
      "securityScheme": [],
      "createdTime": "1676303777293",
      "updatedTime": "1676304136190",
      "gatewayVendor": null,

Comment: The carbon log records the following:
[2023-02-15 13:40:51,635]  INFO {****.DependencyTracker} - Local entry : 7*9f849f5 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2023-02-15 13:40:51,661]  INFO {****.DependencyTracker} - Endpoint : Test-404-Bug--v1.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2023-02-15 13:40:51,701]  INFO {***.DependencyTracker} - API : Test-404-Bug:v1.0.0 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2023-02-15 13:40:51,701]  INFO {**e.synapse.api.API} - {api:Test-404-Bug:v1.0.0} Initializing API: Test-404-Bug:v1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

If you API is only available after server restart and is not available when you deploy, there should be an issue with the jms connection between the CP and GW. API deployment events are not received by the gateway thus preventing them from deploying in the gateway. These events are distributed between CP and GW via jms. APIs get deployed in the restart means, the gateway can reach to event hub (which resides in the same instance because this is an all-in-one deployment) via HTTP.

Shall we add the following configuration and see whether this solves your issue?

```
[apim.event_hub]
enable = true
username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
service_url = "https://<control-plane-host>:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
event_listening_endpoints = ["tcp://<control-plane-host>:5672"]
```

Comment: I'll try more configuration and get back to you right away if there's still an error. This error occurs occasionally after we deploy a new application. Thank you for your support @Lakshitha

Comment: If this is an intermittent error, this config will not solve the issue as this mapping is already maintained with the default configurations and that mapping works in your setting. Then there should be an intermittent network errors with jms connection in localhost.

Comment: Can you describe for me how to test JMS connection between CP and GW? Or is there a JMS connection log anywhere? Services that were running before, now get the same error and have to restart the entire WSO2 (Log carbon: Error:404 / Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /internal/***, HEALTH CHECK URL)